# different mapping for the same url

Tags: url, grails, mapping

I would like to use a different mapping for the same url http://localhost:8080/myapp/ when the user is logged in (session.user)

Actually, as default I`m giving the path when the url is "/" to AppController and 'index' action... but if I try to redirect inside the index action when the user is logged to my UserController (also index action), the path changes to http://localhost:8080/myapp/user/index . That`s not what I`m looking for.

There is a plenty of website (twitter, facebook..) that apply this method, but couldn`t understand how can it be done in Grails, without using the same action for example (AppControlle>index) and render different views when user is active.

```
 static mappings = {
    "/"(controller:"app",action:"index")

    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
      constraints {
        // apply constraints here
      }
    }

    "500"(view:'/error')
    "404"(view:'/notFound')
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your mention about twitter, facebook... I think it's possible that they use different mapping based on the request is POST or GET. In Grails, we can do that kind of mapping like this:

```
name home: "/" {
    controller = [GET: "app", POST: "user"]
    action = [GET: "index", POST: "userIndex"]
}
```